# Auto refresh in news ticker

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my news ticker.
My code for sliding up to tag `li` regularly:

```
<script>
    function ticker(){
        $('.slide li:first').slideUp(function(){
            $(this).appendTo($('.slide')).slideDown();  
        });
    }
    setInterval(function(){ticker()},3000); 
</script>
```

But when I add this code :

```
setInterval(function(){$('.ticker-box').load("ticker.php");},100);
```

sliding up does not work and I need to autorefresh it because that part is connected to the database.

Comment: You want to refresh every 100 milliseconds?

Comment: yes, but the sliding not work or sometime work but not fully sliding up please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

First, your code can cause a DDOS in your own site. What i want to say is your interval is **too short** to any site support it, as a server cannot process that amount of requests in the specified interval with only a few users.

Second, your second code isn't calling the ticker() function, and because of it the sliding up isn't working.

Try something such as:

```
<script>
    function ticker(){
        $('.slide li:first').slideUp(function(){
            $(this).appendTo($('.slide')).slideDown();  
        });
    }
    function refresh(){ 
        $('.ticker-box').load("ticker.php", function(){
            ticker(); // Slide up
            setTimeout(refresh, 1000); // And call the same function in a specified interval of 1 second (as it is more secure)
        })
    }
    refresh();
</script>
```

And is just it.

PS: The change of interval is only a recommendation, if you want to change it and has a server with highest performance, you can change it with freedom.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, I'll try that way :)

Comment: @ginc0de Just alert if you have any problems or questions about the code. :)

Comment: What's the error reported by Javascript and/or PHP? If you want, put these codes in a gist, here: http://gist.github.com/ - and send me the link generated. :)

Comment: here the sql : https://gist.github.com/ginc0der/5464431 and other file : https://gist.github.com/ginc0der/5464454